# Changing the image of a scroll bar without flash

Tags: css, slider, browser-scrollbars

How can i change the appearance (not the color) of a scrollbar within a box with overflow? I know how to do it in flash, I need a way to do it without it. In fact, I want to know how they did this slider in the apple web site: http://www.apple.com/mac/
It seems they used css along with javascript, but that's all I know. Is it possible that they did it using DOM, DHTML, HTML 5, Ruby or PHP? I have no idea.

If you'd be kind enough to share the answer, I thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! They helped me enormously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They basically re-created a fake scrollbar using images, CSS and some Javascript. When you drag the image, Javascript makes it move together with the mouse cursor and scrolls the box contents in the opposite direction. The real scrollbar is being hidden/deactivated using CSS.

Look here for some examples/tutorials: http://www.hiddenpixels.com/javascript/custom-javascript-scrollbar/